# closing box is need to apply when this relevant code is missing

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the input xml as follows. In this xml, sometimes, `<par class="endboxa">` is missing. But, anyway i need to match this input and output box equally on the output. I mean whenever, the `endboxa` is missing, then, anyway, i need to do match this. Any help?

input xml
[code]

```
<par class="startboxa"><inline style="border-bottom-width: 3.0pt; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: #ff0000; list-style-type: decimal; "></inline></par>
<par class="para" xml:lang="de"><inline style="list-style-type: decimal; ">Alle Aspekte der Verfügbarkeit und alle Phasen des Servicelebenszyklus sind bei den Service Design Aktivitäten zu berücksichtigen.</inline></par>
<par class="para" xml:lang="de"><inline style="list-style-type: decimal; ">Der Beitrag des Availability Management zu den Design-Aktivitäten ist:</inline></par>
<par class="para" xml:lang="de"><inline style="list-style-type: decimal; ">Können die Verfügbarkeitsanforderungen nicht eingehalten indem geprüft wird, ob eine entsprechend leistungsfähige Technologie in das vorgeschlagene IT-Design implementiert werden kann. Beispiel:</inline></par>

<par class="startboxa"><inline style="border-bottom-width: 3.0pt; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: #ff0000; list-style-type: decimal; "></inline></par>
<par class="para" xml:lang="de"><inline style="list-style-type: decimal; font-weight: bold; ">Hinweise und Tipps</inline></par>
<par class="para" xml:lang="de"><inline style="list-style-type: decimal; ">Dokugen werden und in geeignete Governance-Strukturen integriert werden, die auf die Einführung neuer IT Services ausgerichtet sind.</inline></par>
<par class="endboxa"><inline style="list-style-type: decimal; border-top-width: 3.0pt; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: #ff0000; "></inline></par>
```

[/code]

My xslt code as of now, I need to updated based on the advise

```
<xsl:template match="par[@class = 'startboxa']">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div class="panel"&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="par[@class = 'endboxa']">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/div&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

output XML [Now I am getting]

[code]

```
<div class="panel">
<p class="para">Alle Aspekte der Verfügbarkeit und alle Phasen des Servicelebenszyklus sind bei den Service Design Aktivitäten zu berücksichtigen.</inline></p>
<p class="para">Der Beitrag des Availability Management zu den Design-Aktivitäten ist:</inline></p>
<p class="para">Können die Verfügbarkeitsanforderungen nicht eingehalten indem geprüft wird, ob eine entsprechend leistungsfähige Technologie in das vorgeschlagene IT-Design implementiert werden kann. Beispiel:</inline></p>

<div class="panel">
<p class="para">Hinweise und Tipps</inline></p>
<p class="para">Dokugen werden und in geeignete Governance-Strukturen integriert werden, die auf die Einführung neuer IT Services ausgerichtet sind.</inline></p>
</div>
```

[/code]

Correct output XML[that i need]

[code]

```
<div class="panel">
<p class="para">Alle Aspekte der Verfügbarkeit und alle Phasen des Servicelebenszyklus sind bei den Service Design Aktivitäten zu berücksichtigen.</inline></p>
<p class="para">Der Beitrag des Availability Management zu den Design-Aktivitäten ist:</inline></p>
<p class="para">Können die Verfügbarkeitsanforderungen nicht eingehalten indem geprüft wird, ob eine entsprechend leistungsfähige Technologie in das vorgeschlagene IT-Design implementiert werden kann. Beispiel:</inline></p>
</div>[`here i need closing tag`]

<div class="panel">
<p class="para">Hinweise und Tipps</inline></p>
<p class="para">Dokugen werden und in geeignete Governance-Strukturen integriert werden, die auf die Einführung neuer IT Services ausgerichtet sind.</inline></p>
</div>
```

[/code]

Comment: Please show your XSLT code.

Comment: I could not make that possible, so, i tried and i am trying, and also, I am copying here

Comment: Why are you generating escaped tags? You should use normal HTML tags.

Comment: ok, thats fine, do you have an answer to my question, Could you please help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this as XSLT 2.0, which is good, as you should be able to use **xsl:for-each-group** here, to group your **par** elements, starting with the "startboxa" one

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="par" group-starting-with="par[@class='startboxa']">
```

With this approach, you don't actually have to worry about whether the 'endboxa' exists or not. Just output a **div** and output everything within it

```
   <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
   </div>
```

This would pick up the "startboxa", and the "endboxa" (if it is exists), so you just need two matching templates to ignore them (unless you did want to output something different for them)

```
    <xsl:template match="par[@class = 'startboxa']" />

    <xsl:template match="par[@class = 'endboxa']" />
```

Try this XSLT. This assumes your current XML is part of a parent element called **parent**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="par" group-starting-with="par[@class='startboxa']">
            <div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par[@class = 'para']">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates /></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par[@class = 'startboxa']" />

    <xsl:template match="par[@class = 'endboxa']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: If you did actually wanted an XSLT 1.0 solution, you can replicate the "group-starting-with" by defining a key that groups the **par** elements by their first most preceding "startboxa" element

```
<xsl:key name="par" match="par[not(@class='startboxa')]" 
                    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::par[@class='startboxa'][1])" />
```

You then change the **xsl:for-each-group** to just an **xsl:for-each** to get the 'starting' element

```
<xsl:for-each select="par[@class='startboxa']">
```

Then, to get the elements in the group, you can use the key

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('par', generate-id())" />
```

The main difference is the key does not actually include the 'startboxa' element itself, so you don't need the extra template to ignore it.

Try this XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="par" match="par[not(@class='startboxa')]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::par[@class='startboxa'][1])" />

    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <xsl:for-each select="par[@class='startboxa']">
            <div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('par', generate-id())" />
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par[@class = 'para']">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates /></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par[@class = 'endboxa']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It can be made to work in XSLT 1.0, but you did tag your question XSLT 2.0, and if you can use XSLT 2.0, you should! If you want an XSLT 1.0 answer, you need to change your question to make it clear you wanted an XSLT 1.0 solution. Thank you.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the XSLT 1.0 solution in this case.